# Fetch outgoing edge property value between two vertices in scala gremlin

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to fetch edge property value between two vertices. E.g. A-->B
A and B are two vertices and it has edge with property(name).

My code looks like:

```
graph.V().hasLabel(A).outE().value("name").headOption()
```

It gives me the property value for name.

In a given two vertices, i am getting None as output

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel(A).outE("test").outV().hasLabel(B).properties("name").headOption()
```

'**test**' - Edge Label
'**name**' - Edge property

Any idea what is wrong with my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for not being able to answer this in your comments on the previous question you asked. I think what you are looking for is:

```
graph.traversal().V()
     .hasLabel("A").outE("test").as("x").otherV()
     .hasLabel("B").select("x").properties("name");
```

If you just want the values of the properties on the edge you can do the following:

```
graph.traversal().V()
     .hasLabel("A").outE("test").as("x").otherV()
     .hasLabel("B").select("x").values("name");
```

**Side Note (Why is your original traversal wrong):** Your original traversal:

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel(A).outE("test").outV().hasLabel(B).properties("name").headOption()
```

is doing the following:

1. Get all vertices with the label `"A"`
2. From those vertices follow the outward going edges which have the label `"test"` to vertices which have the label "B"
3. Then get the property `"name"` from those vertices

You are actually asking for the properties on the vertex.